# Apache POI Missing Cell Policy skips last cell if empty

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have written a snippet to read the Excel values and manipulate in Java. If the last cell of any row is empty it is not being read.

```
       while (rows.hasNext()) {
            Map<Integer, Object> columnDataMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();

            row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();

            for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                cell = row.getCell(i, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                short fontIndex = cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex();
                Font f = wb.getFontAt(fontIndex);

                if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
                      columnDataMap.put(cell.getColumnIndex(), WFMTConstants.EMPTY_STRING);
                  }

                if (!(f.getBoldweight() == Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD) ){

                columnDataMap.put(cell.getColumnIndex(), cell.toString());
                }
            }
            rowDataMap.put(row.getRowNum(), columnDataMap);
           }
```

How to ensure that the last cell will be read if it is empty? If all rows generally have 7 columns and for eg. row 3 has 6 columns and 7th is empty, the 7th one should also be read as null but for that row row.getLastCellNum() returns 6.

Comment: Keep track of the highest column number in use, and fetch based on that rather than a per-row number?

Comment: That's how I have changed later it but isn't there any other option?

Comment: What magical property do you think there is in your excel file that'll detail that?